# how to insert properly in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to insert data into database for using yii2.
It is working well but I having a little problem each time 
insert it goes into the database and the field becomes empty.
But when I refresh it goes back it to the database again.
Any time I refresh it adds the same data to the database  again and I don't know why.

the is my controller class

```
   public function actionCompose() {

        $topic = new Topic();
        $topic->load($_POST);
        $topic->save();

        return $this->render('compose');
    }
```

this is my view class compose.php

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<input type="name"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">
<textarea type="name"  cols="30" rows="10"  class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[about]" id="" placeholder="about"></textarea>
<input type="name" class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[category]" id="category" placeholder="category">

<?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>   
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Pls provide validation rules in your Topic Model

Comment: and can you do print_r($topic->errors); after  $topic->save(); and tell us what is print out

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your code as:

```
public function actionCompose()
{
    $topic= new Topic(); 
    //assuming post() request
    if($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $topic->validate()){
     //save() must be after validate() 
     $topic->save();
    }

    return $this->render('compose');
}
```

If still occurs provide validation rules in your Post Model

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be check your model before save that is posted or no!

```
public function actionCompose() {
    $topic = new Topic();
    if($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $topic->save();
    }

    return $this->render('compose');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking that request is POST or normal request.

```
public function actionCompose()
{
   $topic= new Topic(); 

    // POST request
    if ($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {
        $topic->load($_POST);
        $topic->save();

        return $this->redirect(['index']); // change name as yours
    }
    else  // Not a form submission
    {
      return $this->render('compose', [
          'model' => $topic, // change name as yours
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i modified it i needed to add return `return $this->refresh();`

```
 public function actionCompose()
    {
     $topic= new Topic(); 

        if ($topic->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $topic->validate()) {
            $topic->load($_POST);
        $topic->save();
        return $this->refresh();
           }
           return $this->render('compose');
    }
```